# Strategy for merging many VCFs

Tags: vcf, bcftools, merge

Can anyone suggest a strategy for speeding up VCF merging?

I have ~44,000 single-sample VCFs that I am trying to merge into a multi-sample VCF with `bcftools merge`, but the job keeps timing out on the cluster (just timed out after 4 days). I could obviously try running it for a couple of weeks, but I was hoping there is a better strategy someone can suggest?

The exact command I am running is

```
bcftools merge --no-version -m all -i 'DP:avg,RO:avg,AO:avg' -F + -o merged.vcf --file-list merge.fofn
```

Happy to try any other tool that will give the same merge results.

Answer (score 4):

We created this over the pandemic when we needed to merge loads of VCFs which all have the same header and first few columns (ie same variants)

https://github.com/iqbal-lab-org/ivcfmerge

That page gives detailed instructions but i'll paste a couple of examples
of how you can use it

== In Python
=4.1.1 If the number of input files is small (can be opened all at once)

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from ivcfmerge import ivcfmerge

filenames = [...]    # List/iterator of relative/absolute paths to input files
output_path = '...'  # Where to write the merged VCF to

with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = map(lambda fname: stack.enter_context(open(fname)), filenames)
    with open(output_path) as outfile:
        ivcfmerge(files, outfile)
```

=4.1.2 If the number of input files is big (cannot be opened all at once)
from ivcfmerge import ivcfmerge_batch

```
filenames = [...]    # List/iterator of relative/absolute paths to input files
output_path = '...'  # Where to write the merged VCF to
batch_size = 1000    # How many files to open and merge at once

ivcfmerge_batch(filenames, output_path, batch_size)
```

Pretty sure we initially did batched bcftools merge, I can't honestly remember why we moved to this. Thankfully not having to do these merges very often

Comment: Thanks Zam. Unfortunately I fail the first two assumptions listed in the README.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using an iterative approach (inspired by [this post](https://shicheng-guo.github.io/bioinformatics/1923/02/28/bcftools-merge)), which took 1.5 hours - so a massive speed up (and that was just the sequential version).

Note: [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) is analogous to `find`, but way nicer to use.

First, merge subsets of *n* VCFs

```
# size of the subsets
n=200
# create file of filenames for each subset
fd -e vcf . path/to/vcfs/ | split -l $n --additional-suffix '.fofn' - subset_vcfs
```

`-e vcf` tells `fd` to find all files with a `.vcf` extension, you can obviously change this to `.bcf`/`.vcf.gz` etc. if necessary. `split` splits the list of all VCFs files into subsets of size `-l` (200) and creates the file of filenames with the prefix `subset_vcfs`. It will add a random suffix to this - e.g. `subset_vcfsav`. Plus the additional suffix `.fofn`. See the [`split` manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) for all options.

Now iterate through these subsets and merge the VCFs listed in them.

### Subset merge option 1 - sequential

This just merges the VCFs one at a time

```bash
for sub in *.fofn;
do
    echo "Merging subset ${sub}..."
    out_vcf="merge.${sub}.bcf"
    bcftools merge --file-list "$sub" -o "$out_vcf"
    bcftools index "$out_vcf"
done
```

### Subset merge option 2 - parallel

You can easily parallelise the previous step using `fd` on the subset files. See [this post](https://mbh.sh/2020-06-22-cheap-parallelisation/) for more details. Or basic [bash `for` loop parallelisation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop).

Create a script (`merge_subset.sh`) of what we want to run on each subset

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sub="$1"
echo "Merging subset ${sub}..."
out_vcf="merge.${sub}.bcf"
bcftools merge --file-list "$sub" -o "$out_vcf"
bcftools index "$out_vcf"
```

Now we run this script with each subset file of filenames using `fd`

```
# number of processes to use. remove this option to use all available
jobs=4
fd -j $jobs -e fofn -x bash merge_subset.sh '{}'
```

### Final merge

Now we merge all of these VCFs into our final VCF

```
ls merge.*.bcf > merged.fofn
bcftools merge -o merged.bcf --file-list merged.fofn
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform a tree based merge of the files.

- Sort the files into groups that can easily be merged in a measurable amount of time.
- Merge each group into a separate Variant Call Format (VCF) file

  - Has the benefit that files can also be grouped by type / source / run
  - Further benefit that small merges can be checked to ensure you like the output before proceeding to the next stage.
  - Further benefit that there are also subgroup files available to be distributed or shared separately.
  - Downside, extra storage space until you have a final product.
- Merge subfiles upward in stages until you arrive at a complete 44,000 entry file

  - If you're happy with the earlier test results, process can be automated with relatively simple iterative shell scripts.
  - Possibly faster, as the bulk merge needs to load every single file into memory, and you may be hitting a capacity bottleneck.
  - Worked in Fluid Dynamics for years, and often ran into a similar issue.  Could run many small cases representing a large case faster than running the large case, because large case would overwhelm memory and transfer capacity.
  - In some clusters you may also be causing nodes to silently crash, which then stalls the entire process without a visible notification.